# How to configure VSCode to automatically open a text file when I open a saved workspace?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am new to VSCode, just started using workspaces.

I was wondering if there is a way to configure my workspace (named fun_projects), to automatically open two text files, as I open the workspace. Like as I open the workspace, I want two previously saved text files to open

Answer (score 1):

You can make a task like this:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Open two files on workspace open or reload",
      "type": "shell",

      // -r flag re-uses the current vscode window
      // note the double-escaping for this form of backslashed paths

      "command": "code -r 'C:\\Users\\Mark\\OneDrive\\folder-operations\\providers.js' 'C:\\Users\\Mark\\OneDrive\\folder-operations\\test.json'",

      // the above can be shortened with the use of a variable:
      "command": "code -r '${workspaceFolder}\\providers.js' '${workspaceFolder}\\test.json'",

      "problemMatcher": [],
      "runOptions": {
        "runOn": "folderOpen"    // makes this task run on folder open
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

That goes into your `tasks.json` file in the `.vscode` folder at the root of your workspace.

It isn't the fastest operation as other vscode set-up occurs first, but it works.

> For the Insiders Build, you would use `code-insiders -r ...`.